# Get rid of glyphicon from input tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have below code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"placeholder="Model" name="pdq">
    </div>
</div>
```

which gives this:

[image]

Question:
How can I get rid of the glyphicon on the right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Glyphicons from Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849102/remove-glyphicons-from-bootstrap)

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue - are you sure you don't have a browser extension/plugin adding that for you?

Comment: @ochi, I'm not sure, because my other input tags don't show any glyphicons....How do I know if a browser extension/plugin did that?

Comment: use a different browser? / disable all extensions?

Comment: you're right! thanks! it's because of the extensions

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate the issue - **see demo below**.

Are you sure you don't have a browser extension/plugin adding that for you?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group col-xs-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Model" name="pdq">
 </div>
</div>
```